# Celery Beat: Limit to single task instance at a time

Tags: python, concurrency, rabbitmq, celery, celerybeat

I have celery beat and celery (four workers) to do some processing steps in bulk. One of those tasks is roughly along the lines of, "for each X that hasn't had a Y created, create a Y."

The task is run periodically at a semi-rapid rate (10sec). The task completes very quickly. There are other tasks going on as well.

I've run into the issue multiple times in which the beat tasks apparently become backlogged, and so the same task (from different beat times) are executed simultaneously, causing incorrectly duplicated work. It also appears that the tasks are executed out-of-order.

1. Is it possible to limit celery beat to ensure only one outstanding instance of a task at a time? Is setting something like `rate_limit=5` on the task the "correct" way to of doing this?
2. Is it possible to ensure that beat tasks are executed in-order, e.g. instead of dispatching a task, beat adds it to a task chain?
3. What's the best way of handling this, short of making those tasks themselves execute atomically and are safe to be executed concurrently? That was not a restriction I would have expected of beat tasks…

The task itself is defined naïvely:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10))
def add_y_to_xs():
    # Do things in a database
    return
```

Here's an actual (cleaned) log:

- `[00:00.000]` foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs sent. id->#1
- `[00:00.001]` Received task: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#1]
- `[00:10.009]` foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs sent. id->#2
- `[00:20.024]` foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs sent. id->#3
- `[00:26.747]` Received task: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#2]
- `[00:26.748]` TaskPool: Apply #2
- `[00:26.752]` Received task: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#3]
- `[00:26.769]` Task accepted: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#2] pid:26528
- `[00:26.775]` Task foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#2] succeeded in 0.0197986490093s: None
- `[00:26.806]` TaskPool: Apply #1
- `[00:26.836]` TaskPool: Apply #3
- `[01:30.020]` Task accepted: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#1] pid:26526
- `[01:30.053]` Task accepted: foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#3] pid:26529
- `[01:30.055]` foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#1]: Adding Y for X id #9725
- `[01:30.070]` foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#3]: Adding Y for X id #9725
- `[01:30.074]` Task foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#1] succeeded in 0.0594762689434s: None
- `[01:30.087]` Task foocorp.tasks.add_y_to_xs[#3] succeeded in 0.0352867960464s: None

We're currently using Celery 3.1.4 with RabbitMQ as the transport.

**EDIT** Dan, here's what I came up with:

Dan, here's what I ended up using:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError
from contextlib import contextmanager


def _psql_advisory_lock_blocking(conn, lock_id, shared, timeout):
    lock_fn = (func.pg_advisory_xact_lock_shared
               if shared else
               func.pg_advisory_xact_lock)
    if timeout:
        conn.execute(text('SET statement_timeout TO :timeout'),
                     timeout=timeout)
    try:
        conn.execute(select([lock_fn(lock_id)]))
    except DBAPIError:
        return False
    return True


def _psql_advisory_lock_nonblocking(conn, lock_id, shared):
    lock_fn = (func.pg_try_advisory_xact_lock_shared
               if shared else
               func.pg_try_advisory_xact_lock)
    return conn.execute(select([lock_fn(lock_id)])).scalar()


class DatabaseLockFailed(Exception):
    pass


@contextmanager
def db_lock(engine, name, shared=False, block=True, timeout=None):
    """
    Context manager which acquires a PSQL advisory transaction lock with a
    specified name.
    """
    lock_id = hash(name)

    with engine.begin() as conn, conn.begin():
        if block:
            locked = _psql_advisory_lock_blocking(conn, lock_id, shared,
                                                  timeout)
        else:
            locked = _psql_advisory_lock_nonblocking(conn, lock_id, shared)
        if not locked:
            raise DatabaseLockFailed()
        yield
```

And the celery task decorator (used only for periodic tasks):

```
from functools import wraps
from preo.extensions import db


def locked(name=None, block=True, timeout='1s'):
    """
    Using a PostgreSQL advisory transaction lock, only runs this task if the
    lock is available. Otherwise logs a message and returns `None`.
    """
    def with_task(fn):
        lock_id = name or 'celery:{}.{}'.format(fn.__module__, fn.__name__)

        @wraps(fn)
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                with db_lock(db.engine, name=lock_id, block=block,
                             timeout=timeout):
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except DatabaseLockFailed:
                logger.error('Failed to get lock.')
                return None
        return f
    return with_task
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very thorough solution with advisory locks, and much cleaner than mine with `@contextmanager`. I was puzzled by the lack of unlock until I realized you were using transaction-level locking... was that simply for convenience or is there another reason to choose it?

Comment: I changed `SET statement_timeout TO :timeout` to `SET LOCAL lock_timeout TO :timeout` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html). This way you won't affect any long-running non-locking statements in the session. (Probably not an issue since you said yours run quickly!)

Comment: @DanLenski That seems like a good change, thank you. Most of our helper functions are wrapped in sub-transactions and so I'm using transaction-level locking to ensure global locks aren't held needlessly long when there is other work being one in the same session.

Comment: But I just realized that by creating a new connection (`conn.begin()`), there's no reason to use a transaction lock rather than session lock. Likewise, there's no reason to differentiate `lock_timeout` and `statement_timeout` in this case either as far as I understand.

Comment: @erydo just my week got better... )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to do this is [implementing a locking strategy yourself](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial):

Read under the section [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) for the reference.

> Like with cron, the tasks may overlap if the first task does not
>   complete before the next. If that is a concern you should use a
>   locking strategy to ensure only one instance can run at a time (see
>   for example Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a task decorator that guards the task with a PostgreSQL advisory lock. I went this route so that workers on separate machines can maintain a single synchronized lock point. (We're not currently using memcached as in the example).

Comment: @erydo, would you be willing to share that decorator? I'm trying to do nearly the same thing and running into some odd synchronization issues.

Comment: i think you'll still have backlogged tasks if you say, had only one worker for this one task. Would need that extra worker to prevent the backlogging

Answer (score 13):

```
from functools import wraps
from celery import shared_task


def skip_if_running(f):
    task_name = f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}'

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        workers = self.app.control.inspect().active()

        for worker, tasks in workers.items():
            for task in tasks:
                if (task_name == task['name'] and
                        tuple(args) == tuple(task['args']) and
                        kwargs == task['kwargs'] and
                        self.request.id != task['id']):
                    print(f'task {task_name} ({args}, {kwargs}) is running on {worker}, skipping')

                    return None

        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


@shared_task(bind=True)
@skip_if_running
def test_single_task(self):
    pass


test_single_task.delay()
```

Comment: what in the world is "clr_app" and how do I import it? Wow. I'm a dummy. It's just @app.task...

Comment: For Django users with `shared_task` decorator: Use the above code with `@shared_task(bind=true)` and the function with `self` as first parameter `def your_task(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue using [celery-once](https://github.com/TrackMaven/celery-once) which I extended to [celery-one](https://github.com/TrackMaven/celery-one).

Both serve for your issue. It uses Redis to lock a running task. `celery-one` will also keep track of the task which is locking.

A very simple usage example for celery beat follows. In the code below, `slow_task` is scheduled every 1 second, but it's completion time is 5 seconds. Normal celery would schedule the task each second even if it is already running. `celery-one` would prevent this.

```
celery = Celery('test')
celery.conf.ONE_REDIS_URL = REDIS_URL
celery.conf.ONE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60
celery.conf.BROKER_URL = REDIS_URL
celery.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_URL

from datetime import timedelta

celery.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.slow_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        'args': (1,)
    },
}

celery.conf.CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'


@celery.task(base=QueueOne, one_options={'fail': False})
def slow_task(a):
    print("Running")
    sleep(5)
    return "Done " + str(a)
```

Comment: Please a) include the relevant parts of the answer here and b) declare your interest in the site. This was being flagged as spam so I deleted it for you.

Comment: I've undeleted your answer and invalidated the spam flag. Thanks for following up.

Comment: The celery-one link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I took a crack at writing a decorator to use [Postgres advisory locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) similar to what erydo alluded to in his comment.

It's not very pretty, but seems to work correctly. This is with SQLAlchemy 0.9.7 under Python 2.7.

```
from functools import wraps
from sqlalchemy import select, func

from my_db_module import Session # SQLAlchemy ORM scoped_session

def pg_locked(key):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kw):
            session = db.Session()
            try:
                acquired, = session.execute(select([func.pg_try_advisory_lock(key)])).fetchone()
                if acquired:
                    return f(*args, **kw)
            finally:
                if acquired:
                    session.execute(select([func.pg_advisory_unlock(key)]))
        return wrapped
    return decorator

@app.task
@pg_locked(0xdeadbeef)
def singleton_task():
    # only 1x this task can run at a time
    pass
```

(Would welcome any comments on ways to improve this!)

Comment: Dan, yep, that's essentially equivalent to what I came up with—I've added my solution as an edit. It includes support for non-blocking lock attempts and configurable timeouts, since I ended up using the locking code in another place as well.

Answer (score 1):

A distributed locking system is required, for those Celery beat instances are essentially different processes which might be across different hosts.

Central coordinate systems such as ZooKeeper and etcd is suitable for implementation of distributed locking system.

I recommend using etcd, which is lightweight and fast. There are several implementations of lock over etcd, such as:

[python-etcd-lock](https://github.com/haizi-zh/python-etcd-lock)

Comment: Distributed locking is a great suggestion, but not strictly required. Centralized locking is fine as long as everything is referring to the same center. In our case, these celery workers all interact with the same master Postgres database anyway.etcd, ZooKeeper, or consul are great suggestions here though.