# Preventing duplicity while scheduling tasks with celery beat

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a task that I run periodically (each minute) via Celery Beat. On occasions, the task will take longer than a minute to finish it's execution, which results in the scheduler adding that task to the queue while the task is already running.

Is there a way I can avoid the scheduler adding tasks to the queue if those tasks are already running?

Edit: I have seen [Celery Beat: Limit to single task instance at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894771/celery-beat-limit-to-single-task-instance-at-a-time)

Note that my question is different. I'm asking how to avoid my task being **enqueued**, while that question is asking how to avoid the task being ran multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had this particular problem but a similar one where I had to avoid tasks being applied when a task of the same kind was already running or queued but without Celery Beat. I went down a similar route, with a locking mechanism, as the answer you've linked here. Unfortunately it won't be that easy here as you want to avoid to queue already.

As far as I know Celery doesn't support anything like this out of the box. I guess your best bet is to write a custom scheduler which inherits from `Scheduler` and then overwrite the `apply_entry` [method](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/beat.html#Scheduler.apply_entry) or the `apply_async` [method](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/beat.html#Scheduler.apply_async). In there you'd need a locking mechanism to check if the task is already running, i.e. in the task set and release a lock and in `apply_async` check for that lock. You could use [RedLock](https://pypi.org/project/redlock/) if you have a Redis running already.